# Using grid in a modal with form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Trying to use grid to create areas in a modal with forms without success. In the bellow case, the modal-footer got weird.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Khrys/s52dr/show)

```
<div>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span>AA</span></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="">Cancelar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs to wrap it in `<div class="container-fluid"></div>`

Comment: Are you sure that works. If I wrap the example from your Fiddle in a `div class='container-fluid`, it still looks messed up.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `overflow` of `.modal-body` to `hidden` it fixes your issue.

```
 .modal-body {
   position: relative;
   padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

For your info— from CSS Tricks : http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/

```
One more popular uses of setting overflow, strangely enough, is float clearing. 
Setting overflow doesn't clear the float at the element, it self-clears. This 
means that  the element with overflow applied (auto or hidden), 
will extend as large as it needs to encompass child elements inside that 
are floated (instead of collapsing), assuming that the height isn't declared.
```

Comment: Just found I need to use `<div class="container-fluid"></div>`. Thanks.